# CanCan allow actions only if the current_user was associated with a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I am using `cancan` for authorisation, and I would like to make some restrictions based on a many to many relationship.

Entities

```
 User - has_many project_assignments
 User - has_many projects, through: :project_assignments

 User - has_many roles, through: :project_assignments
```

ProjectAssignment: user_id, project_id, role_id

I want to give the user the ability to do a full `CRUD` on `Project and Toy` models, only if the project was created by the user. Toy is nested under Project

`Toy has many Projects` and `Project has many Toy` through `ProjectToy`

```
 if user.role? :moderator
   can :crud, [Project, Toy]
 end
```

I think I only need to restrict the `project`, because `toy` is depending on the project_id, can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

In my Project controller I have added:

`load_and_authorize_resource through: :current_user`

In my Toy controller I added:

`load_and_authorize_resource project, through: :current_user`
`load_and_authorize_resource :toy, through: :project`

In my Ability file:

```
if user.role? :moderator
   can :crud, :all or [Project, Toy]
end
```

And everything is working fine, I`ve assigned a user to multiple projects, and it has access to each project.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use some kind of if statement for the second many to many:

```
can :crud, Project do |project|
  ProjectAssignment.where(user_id: user.id, project_id: project.id).any?
end

can :crud, ProjectToy do |project_toy|
  ProjectAssignment.where(user_id: user.id, project_id: project_toy.project.id).any?
  if can? :crud, ProjectToy
    can :crud, Toy do |toy|
      ProjectToy.where(toy_id: toy.id).any?
    end
  end
end
```

PS - You may need to be careful with :crud and replace this with [:edit, :update, :destroy, :delete] then give a separate can to :create because if the user is creating a project/toy for the first time then the system won't find any toys or projects associated with him/her and not provide access.

Comment: can't do that, because toys and projects have a many to many relationship

Comment: So it's like this? User -> has many -> Project Assignments -> belongs to -> Project -> has many -> Project Keywords -> belongs to -> Toy

Comment: Yep is like that.. ProjectToy, not ProjectKeywords I just edited that... sorry

Comment: Thank you, but I've found a cleaner solution, maybe better.